# best way to convert MockHttpServletResponse to ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

just wondering what is the simpler/best way to convert MockHttpServletResponse to ResponseEntity

the background is I have my tests currently using TestRestTemplate and plan to migrate them to use MockMvc

the situation is that  MockMvc.perform(...).getResponse() returns a MockHttpServletResponse and TestRestTemplate.exchange(...) returns a ResponseEntity

I wanted to know if there is any out of the box way of doing this conversion and if not what is the best way? At the moment the only workaround I have is to ignore the ResponseEntity and just use directly the instance with a json mapper conversion from the string

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box support for such a conversion. The two approaches (`RestTemplate` vs. `MockMvc`) are very different. So I think you'll have to manually rewrite the tests.

Comment: With regards to checking the content of the response with `MockMvc`, people typically use `jsonPath()` variants for that. However, if you really want to convert a JSON response body into a domain object for direct comparison via `.equals()`, then you would indeed need to obtain the content as a `String` and use a Jackson Mapper.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, in the meantime I've re-wrote most tests and they seem to work fine but I was just wondering if there was any magic way of converting the mock response into a ResponseEntity